# Java Server Pages module for Apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

What is the Java Server Pages module for Apache, and what is its function?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat is already a JSP servlet; there's no need for a "module".

mod_jk is the module that connects Apache Tomcat to Apache HTTPd. It proxies requests from HTTPd to Tomcat.